# Is there a chart/report in Azure DevOps to see completed work in current sprint per developer?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

We want to have a chart or some other way of report for our team to see how much time we spent on our tasks since the start of the sprint, grouped by each developer/team member. Similar to the burndown chart but only tracking newly added "Completed Work" to a task in the sprint and not adding the completed work for all developers (the burndown for Completed Work seems to add up all completed work, so if a task was moved over with 12 hours already clocked for example it adds that, too, even though we do not want this in our chart).

Does Azure DevOps have this capability or is there an add on for this?

Comment: Hi @Lofter, have you checked the suggestions below? Are the custom query chart and analytics views helpful for you? Feel free to let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom query and use the chart to visualize the result.  For example, add the following filter conditions and add **Completed Work** from Column options.
[image]

Save the query and go to **Charts**. Create a new chart and take the second chart for example.

- Group by: Assigned To
- Aggregation: Sum of Completed Work

[image]

Then you can see the chart as shown below:
[image]

In addition, you can also create analytics views and then connect to Power BI to customize your report. See more detailed info from [About Power BI integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/overview?view=azure-devops). For example,

[image]